# Selecting a list slice, reversing it, and updating the list

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I'm trying to get some guidance on how to implement this algorithm in python. I'm currently trying to solve adventofcode.com/2017/day/10.

I understand the logic of what needs to be done, but where I'm stuck is implementing this in code specifically taking a selection/slice of a list, reversing it, then "putting it back" into said list.

The example they give is:

Suppose we instead only had a circular list containing five elements, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and were given input lengths of `[3, 4, 1, 5]`.

The list begins as `[0] 1 2 3 4` (where square brackets indicate the current position).
The first length, 3, selects `[0] 1 2) 3 4` (where parentheses indicate the sublist to be reversed).
After reversing that section `(0 1 2 into 2 1 0)`, we get `([2] 1 0) 3 4`.
Then, the current position moves forward by the length, 3, plus the skip size, 0: `2 1 0 [3] 4`. Finally, the skip size increases to 1.

The second length, 4, selects a section which wraps: `2 1) 0 ([3] 4`.
The sublist `3 4 2 1` is reversed to form `1 2 4 3: 4 3) 0 ([1] 2`.
The current position moves forward by the length plus the skip size, a total of 5, causing it not to move because it wraps around: `4 3 0 [1] 2`. The skip size increases to 2.

I know I will use a for loop for each length, then based on the current "cursor" position, create a slice that starts at the cursor position, and contains the amount of elements that matches the current iteration (in the second example it would be 4). I feel like this needs to be solved using the %, list slicing, and the length of the list but can't figure it out. Any guidance or help would be much appreciated even if it's resources to learn how to solve this versus just the answer. But I'll take anything. Thanks friends.

Comment: >Suppose we instead only had a circular list... Instead of what?
Please also note that the you provided doe not work. 404 error.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to brute-force the problem. If so, you are on the wrong track. First, try to figure out what element would become the first after all reversals. Hint: apply them backwards.

Comment: Thank you @user58697 I will take your advice and see what I can come up with. @Yuri Ginsburg the link is correct it's `www.adventofcode.com/2017/day/10`.